# Dynamically load content to div but top css style was not applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following codes in `main.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/material.cyan-light_blue.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/styles.css">
<script src="static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/main.js"></script>

<main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
<div id="main-display" class="mdl-grid demo-content">
</div>
</main>
```

In `main.js`,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main-display").load(
        "static/tabs.html",
        function() { $("#main-display").trigger("create");
    });
});
```

And in `tabs.html`, I have

```
<div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
<div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
    <a href="#tab1" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Tab1</a>
    <a href="#tab2" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Tab2</a>
    <a href="#tab3" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Tab3</a>
</div>
```

The problem is when `tabs.html` is loaded by `$("#main-display").load()`, its css style was not applied. The MDL tabs feature did not work.

Comment: Have you tried making only one of the Tab's `is-active`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am using jquery load a new html file, but css doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283893/i-am-using-jquery-load-a-new-html-file-but-css-doesnt-work) Please look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31288866/2893691

Comment: I think the problem is different. The loaded HTML content use the same css in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figure out a solution as follows by modifying `main.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main-display").load(
        "static/tabs.html",
        function() {
            var tabs = document.getElementById("div-js-tabs");
            componentHandler.downgradeElements(tabs);
            componentHandler.upgradeElements(tabs);
        }
    );
});
```

And add `id="div-js-tabs"` to tabs in `tabs.html`.

```
<div id="div-js-tabs" class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
```

Then, when I dynamically load `tabs.html`, its MDL css was applied properly.